# How to implement 1-out-of-n OT from 1-out-of-2 OT?

Tags: protocol-design, oblivious-transfer

How can I implement a 1-out-of-$n$ [oblivious transfer](https://crypto.stanford.edu/pbc/notes/crypto/ot.html) protocol from 1-out-of-2 OT protocol which is resistant against passive corruption? Assume we can access 1-out-of-2 OT $n$ times.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Approach 1**

The simplest way of doing this is for the receiver, with choice $j \in \{1,\dots,n\}$, to input $1$ in the $j$-th 1-out-of-2 OT and $0$ elsewhere. The sender, with input $(x_1, \dots, x_n)$, inputs $(0,x_i)$ in the $i$-th OT.

**Approach 2**

An alternative protocol (that just came out of a discussion with a colleague, and seems to be actively secure) is for the sender to sample $n$ random strings $r_1,\dots,r_n$. Now run $n$ 1-out-of-2 OTs where the sender inputs:

$$
\begin{aligned}
(r_1, \,& x_1) \\
(r_2, \,& r_1 \oplus x_2) \\
(r_3, \,& r_1 \oplus r_2 \oplus x_3) \\
&\vdots \\
(r_n, \,& r_1 \oplus r_2 \oplus r_3 \oplus \dots \oplus r_{n-1} \oplus x_n) \\
\end{aligned}
$$

Now, it should be easy to see how the receiver gets the right choice. The advantage here is that a cheating receiver cannot easily learn any other choices, as each $x_i$ is masked by a fresh random value.

(Caveat: I've only thought very briefly about this and am not 100% sure about its active security)

**Approach 3 (using $\log n$ OTs)**

[Naor and Pinkas](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=301312) gave a protocol using just $\log_2 n$ 1-out-of-2 OTs on $k$-bit strings (for security parameter $k$).
The sender inputs $\log{n}$ random pairs of strings to the 1-out-of-2 OTs, and the receiver inputs their choice represented as $\log n$ bits.

Now for each $i \in \{1,\dots,n\}$, let $b_1^i b_2^i \cdots b_{\log n}^i$ denote the bits of $i$. The $i$-th sender's string is defined as

$$x_i = H(s^1_{b_1^i}\|\cdots\|s^{\log n}_{b_{\log n^i}})$$

where $s^j_0,s^j_1$ are the random strings used in the $j$-th 1-out-of-2 OT.
This gets a 1-out-of-$n$ OT on random strings, which can be easily converted to chosen strings by sending the XOR.

(Note that the Naor-Pinkas protocol used a PRF, but if $H$ is modelled as a random oracle then this works too)

Answer (score 1):

**Tung Chou** and **Claudio Orlandi** created the most efficient 1-out-of-n OT protocol to date, based on an 1-out-of-2 OT protocoln, named **The Simplest Protocol for Oblivious Transfer**. You can read more about it [here](http://users-cs.au.dk/orlandi/simpleOT/).

Comment: Providing sources is nice but far from enough to be a decent answer. Could you please elaborate / summarize the paper ?

Comment: Actually, it's not the most efficient 1-out-of-n OT protocol known; to do it, it uses $O(n)$ modular exponentiations; Naor and Pinkas showed how that can be done with $O(\log n)$ 1-out-of-2 OT's.  This will be more efficient for sufficiently large $n$.