# Most efficient way to implement a 1-out-of-4 OT for GMW?

Tags: multiparty-computation, oblivious-transfer

Assuming evaluation in the online phase (no beaver triple/offline method used), each AND gate in GMW must be evaluated using a 1-out-of-4 OT. I've seen some sources ([here](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Esanjamg/classes/cs276-fall14/scribe/lec16.pdf), and [here](https://eprint.iacr.org/2021/822.pdf)) say this can be implemented using 3 1-out-of-2 OTs over 1 bit strings. Can it also be implemented from 2 1-out-of-2 OTs over 1 bit strings? (Assuming we can treat the 1-out-of-2 OT as a black box).

(Note: I know [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/34639/how-to-implement-1-out-of-n-ot-from-1-out-of-2-ot) question says that a 1-out-of-*n* OT can be implemented from log(*n*) 1-out-of-2 OTs, but that seemed to only be for *k*-bit strings for a security parameter *k*.)